# SonarLint in IntelliJ works with username and password but not with token

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I configure the Server in IntelliJ like this:

> ```
> Name: xsonar
> Server URL: https://sonar.xyz.com/
> Organization: 
> Auth Type: Token
> Token: my-on-sonar-created-token
> Not using proxy
> ```

It says for the test connection:

> Error testing connection: Not authorized. Please check server credentials.

However, if I use identical configuration but with my sonar login and password it works perfectly.

The documentation doesn't say anything about this: http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/

And I didn't find similar issues.

The version of my SonarQube is 6.2.

How dangerous is it to use password and username instead of token?

Answer (score 0):

We had a reversed proxy sitting in between which wouldn't let the request through using our normal proxy. So far I haven't found a good solution to work around the reversed proxy.

Comment: Still no solution at this time? I'm in a similar situation.